# How to simulate vehicle movement in omnet++?

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++, traffic-simulation

I'm new to omnet++, and i need to write a simultaion of vehicle on a map.
i have a compund module called "Vehicle" which contains 2 simple module:

1. for movement (all the cars will move on a map)
2. for the communication between all the vehicle

Somebody know how to implement the movement part?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [VEINS](http://veins.car2x.org/) framework that provides all you need to simulate vehicular networks. Alternatively, the [INETMANET](https://github.com/inetmanet/inetmanet) framework also contains several mobility and wireless communication models.